# How to find $\lim\limits_{x\to0}\frac{e^x-1-x}{x^2}$ without using l'Hopital's rule nor any series expansion?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, limits, exponential-function, limits-without-lhopital

Is it possible to determine the limit

$$\lim_{x\to0}\frac{e^x-1-x}{x^2}$$

without using l'Hopital's rule nor any series expansion?

For example, suppose you are a student that has not studied derivative yet (and so not even Taylor formula and Taylor series).

Comment: Why don't you want to use them ?

Comment: @Belgi: take it as a challenge or a curiosity

Comment: There were couple of questions about limits with l'Hoptial's; you might want to check out [1](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/182999/how-to-evaluate-lim-limits-x-rightarrow-inftyex-e-1-frac1x?rq=1) and [2](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/18319/i-want-to-find-lim-limits-x-to-5-frac2x-25x-5-without-using-lhopital?rq=1).

Comment: This amounts to finding the second derivative of $e^x$ at $x=0$.  So I guess it's important to motivate why you want to restrict methods of proof.  Certainly an approach along the lines that being its own derivative characterizes $e^x$ seems viable.

Comment: What is your definition of $e^x$?

Comment: I suppose that any solution that begins by observing that $e^x= 1+x+\frac12x^2+O(x^3)$ will fail to satisfy you, even though no infinite series is being invoked?

Comment: Graph it using wolfram alpha

Comment: @ChrisEagle: I could take $e^x$ as the $\sup$ of $A=\{e^q|q\in\mathbb{Q},q\leq x\}$.

Comment: @enzotib So the next question is: what is the first property of the exponential that you do not want to use?

Comment: @enzotib: You *could* do any number of things. *Are* you doing that? If yes, what is your definition of $e$?

Comment: @JoelCohen But that would encourage people not to use l'Hopital's, which is a foolish handicap to impose on oneself.

Comment: That rule is just a make up for derivatives.

Comment: @ChrisEagle: the classical definition through the known sequence limit is ok?

Comment: I added a (weak, I know) motivation to the question.

Comment: I am not sure that your definition of $e^x$ works without a definition of $e$ - from your definition so far it could be anything.

Comment: @JoelCohen: I think the tag `alternate-proof` ought to work just fine.

Answer (score 37):

Define $f(x)=\lim_{n\to\infty}\left(1+\frac{x}{n}\right)^n$.  One possibility is to take $f(x)$ as the definition of $e^x$.  Since the OP has suggested a different definition, I will show they agree.

If $x=\frac{p}{q}$ is rational, then
\begin{eqnarray*}
f(x)&=&\lim_{n\to\infty}\left(1+\frac{p}{qn}\right)^n\\
&=&\lim_{n\to\infty}\left(1+\frac{p}{q(pn)}\right)^{pn}\\
&=&\lim_{n\to\infty}\left(\left(1+\frac{1}{qn}\right)^n\right)^p\\
&=&\lim_{n\to\infty}\left(\left(1+\frac{1}{(qn)}\right)^{(qn)}\right)^{p/q}\\
&=&\lim_{n\to\infty}\left(\left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)^{n}\right)^{p/q}\\
&=&e^{p/q}
\end{eqnarray*}
Now, $f(x)$ is clearly non-decreasing, so
$$
\sup_{p/q\leq x}e^{p/q}\leq f(x)\leq \inf_{p/q\geq x}e^{p/q}
$$
It follows that $f(x)=e^x$.

Now, we have
\begin{eqnarray*}
\lim_{x\to0}\frac{e^x-1-x}{x^2}&=&\lim_{x\to0}\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{\left(1+\frac{x}{n}\right)^n-1-x}{x^2}\\
&=&\lim_{x\to0}\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{n-1}{2n}+\sum_{k=3}^n\frac{{n\choose k}}{n^k}x^{k-2}\\
&=&\frac{1}{2}+\lim_{x\to0}x\lim_{n\to\infty}\sum_{k=3}^n\frac{{n\choose k}}{n^k}x^{k-3}\\
\end{eqnarray*}

We want to show that the limit in the last line is 0.  We have $\frac{{n\choose k}}{n^k}\leq\frac{1}{k!}\leq 2^{-(k-3)}$, so we have
\begin{eqnarray*}
\left|\lim_{x\to0}x\lim_{n\to\infty}\sum_{k=3}^n\frac{{n\choose k}}{n^k}x^{k-3}\right|&\leq&\lim_{x\to0}|x|\lim_{n\to\infty}\sum_{k=3}^n \left(\frac{|x|}{2}\right)^{k-3}\\
&=&\lim_{x\to0}|x| \frac{1}{1-\frac{|x|}{2}}\\
&=&0
\end{eqnarray*}

Comment: very good solution. I think a student who doesnt have knowledge about l'Hopital's rule or any series expansion can simply follow your way)))))

Comment: +1 For the stamina shown in the elegant, though long, solution. Yet, I think many students who haven't yet any knowledge of derivatives, L'H rule and series expansion won't probably have the capability to fully understand double limits and ths swift use of summatories.

Comment: Nice way to compute the limit! (+1)

Comment: very elegant solution. This goes on to say what is possible to achieve without a direct use of LHR. Personally I try to avoid to LHR if a limit problem can be solved using rules of algebra of limits. But in this case we have to resort to infinite series and double limits (although of an easy kind), so that LHR is much better suited to this.

Comment: Julian, nice solution.  Just curious as to the relevance of the passage regarding $f(x)$ bounds in terms the supremum and infimum of $e^{p/q}$.  In the development, it was assumed that $x=p/q$; the result was that $e^{p/q}=\lim_{n\to \infty}\left(1+\frac{p/q}{n}\right)^n$.  Are you trying to establish that the limit extends from the rational numbers to the reals?

Answer (score 8):

Let us call our limit $\ell$.
I was considering the following identity

$$
4\frac{e^{2x}-1-2x}{(2x)^2}-2\frac{e^x-1-x}{x^2}=\left(\frac{e^x-1}{x}\right)^2\quad\forall x\ne0
$$

**If $\mathbf{\ell}$ exists and is not infinite**, taking the limit of the above identity we have

$$
4\ell-2\ell=1\implies\ell=\frac{1}{2}
$$

but I am not able to prove the **bold** part above (if at all possible, in a simple way).

Comment: "if at all possible" - ofcourse it is possible, the answer above showed what it is exactly

Comment: @Belgi: of course, but I mean proving that (without calculating the resulting value) in a simpler way.

Comment: @Belgi: No, there is a subtlety here.  For example, consider the series $\sum_{i=0}^{\infty} (-1)^i = 1 - 1 + 1 - 1 + 1 \cdots$.  *If* the sum has a limit, $L$, then it is clear that $L = 1 + \sum_{i=1}^{\infty} (-1)^i = 1 - \sum_{i=0}^{\infty} (-1)^i$.  Therefore, since $L = 1 - L$, $L = 1/2$.  However, since the limit of partial sums $\sum_{i=1}^{N} (-1)^i$ does *not* exist, it cannot be equal to $1/2$.

Comment: @ShaunAult - but considering the above answer the limit of the partial sums does exist so it is **possible** to show that $l$ exist and is finite, this is the only thing I said (I did not say this in general for other sums)

Comment: @Belgi: By "above answer", were you referring to Pink Elephants' answer?

Comment: @Hurkyl - yes (I was counting on it that with $18$ upvotes it will still be the above answer :))

Comment: This answer is really interesting. (+1)

Answer (score 4):

> **I thought it might be useful to present a way forward that relies on an integral representation of the numerator along with the mean-value theorem for integrals.  To that end, we now proceed.**

---

Note that we can write the numerator as

$$\begin{align}
e^x-x-1&=\int_0^x \int_0^t e^s \,ds\,dt\\\\
&=\int_0^x \int_s^x e^s\,dt\,ds\\\\
&=\int_0^x (x-s)e^s\,ds
\end{align}$$

Next, we apply the Mean-Value-Theorem for integrals to reveal

$$\begin{align}
e^x-x-1&=e^{s^*}\int_0^x(x-s)\,ds\\\\
&=\frac12 x^2e^{s^*}
\end{align}$$

for some value of $s^*\in (0,x)$.

Finally, exploiting the continuity of the exponential function yields the coveted limit

$$\begin{align}
\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{e^x-x-1}{x^2}&=\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{\frac12 x^2e^{s^*}}{x^2}\\\\
&=\frac12
\end{align}$$

as expected!

Answer (score 3):

Given the familiar limit ${e^t-1\over t}\to1$ as $t\to0$, we can argue as follows:

$${e^x-1-x\over x^2}={1\over x^2}\int_0^x(e^u-1)\,du={1\over x}\int_0^1(e^{xv}-1)\,dv=\int_0^1v\left(e^{xv}-1\over xv\right)\,dv$$

Now intuitively we have ${e^{xv}-1\over xv}={e^t-1\over t}\to1$ as $xv=t\to0$, hence

$$\int_0^1v\left(e^{xv}-1\over xv\right)\,dv\to\int_0^1v\cdot1\,dv={1\over2}v^2\Big|_0^1={1\over2}$$

but to be rigorous we need to justify the intuition of bringing the limit inside the integral. If you have a fancy enough theorem, you can cite it and be done, but let's do it from first principles: We need to show that for any $\epsilon\gt0$, there is a $\delta\gt0$ such that $0\lt|x|\lt\delta$ implies

$$\left|\int_0^1 v\left(e^{xv}-1\over xv\right)\,dv-{1\over2} \right|=\left|\int_0^1 v\left({e^{xv}-1\over xv}-1\right)\,dv\ \right|\le\epsilon$$

What we *do* know (from the familiar limit) is that for any $\epsilon\gt0$ there is a $\delta\gt0$ such that $0\lt|t|\lt\delta$ implies $\left|{e^t-1\over t}-1\right|\lt\epsilon$. Now if $0\lt|x|\lt\delta$ and $0\lt v\lt1$, then $0\lt|xv|\lt\delta$ as well, so for any $\epsilon\gt0$ we conclude there is a $\delta\gt0$ such that $0\lt|x|\lt\delta$ implies

$$\left|\int_0^1 v\left({e^{xv}-1\over xv}-1\right)\,dv\ \right|\le\int_0^1 v\left|{e^{xv}-1\over xv}-1\right|\,dv\
\le\int_0^1v\epsilon\,dv={\epsilon\over2}\lt\epsilon$$

and we're done.

Remark: The "familiar" limit ${e^t-1\over t}\to1$ as $t\to0$ is the definition of the derivative of the exponential function at $0$. The whole proof here is built around knowing that $(e^x)'=e^x$, in the form $\int_0^xe^u\,du=e^x-1$.

Comment: Approved your very nice solution.

Answer (score 2):

Accidentally I came across this post and I thought of
how to prove the statement
$$ \lim_{x\rightarrow 0} \frac{e^x-1-x}{x^2} = \frac12 .$$
assuming only
that the function $e^x$
satisfies the two properties:
$$ e^{x+y}=e^x e^y \ \mbox{and} \
 \lim_{x\rightarrow 0} \frac{e^x-1}{x} = 1$$

It turns out that it is possible using
$\sum_{k=0}^{n-1} = \frac{n(n-1)}{2}$ and elementary
algebraic properties of limits, but being very careful
with the uniform bounds for these limits.
The proof, although elementary,
is not simple so is probably not of much practical use.
Also, all the difficulties are hidden in the existence of
the function $e^x$ verifying the functional equation.
Anyway, I post it for the curios reader.

To start, note that
the second property for $e^x$ is equivalent to the following:
Write $R(x) = e^x-1-x$. Then
for $\delta>0$ and $|x|\leq \delta$ we have the uniform bound:
$|R(x)|\leq \Delta(\delta)$ with a function $\Delta$ that verifies:
$$\lim_{\delta\rightarrow 0}
\frac{\Delta(\delta)}{\delta} \rightarrow 0.$$

By the above definitions we also have
$|e^x|\leq M(\delta) \equiv  1+\delta+\Delta(\delta)
<+\infty$.

Fix $x\neq 0$, $L=\Delta(|x|)/|x|$, $M=M(|x|)$
and let $n\geq 1$. Using the functional equation
for $e^x$ we may rewrite $e^x-1=e^{nx/n}-1$ as a
telescopic sum:

$$ e^x-1=
\sum_{k=0}^{n-1} 
e^{\frac{k}{n} x} 
\left(
e^{\frac{x}{n}} 
-1\right)=
\sum_{k=0}^{n-1} 
\left( 1+ \frac{k}{n}x + R(\frac{k}{n}x) \right)
\left( \frac{x}{n} + R(\frac{x}{n}) \right)
$$
Developing the RHS
and using $\sum_{k=0}^{n-1} k = \frac{n^2-n}{2}$
we get the expression $x + \frac{n-1}{2n} x^2$
plus an error term which is bounded by
$$
\sum_{k=0}^{n-1} 
\left[ \Delta( \frac{k}{n}|x|) 
\times  (1+L) \frac{|x|}{n}+
e^{\frac{k}{n} x}  
 \Delta(\frac{|x|}{n}) \right] \leq 
n \Delta(|x|) 
\times  (1+L) \frac{|x|}{n}
 + M n  \times
 \Delta(\frac{|x|}{n})  $$
Therefore,
$$\left| \frac{e^x-(1+x+x^2/2)}{x^2} \right| \leq \frac{x^2}{2n} +
  (1+L) \frac{\Delta(|x|)}{|x|}  
 + M  \frac{1}{|x|} \frac{\Delta(|x|/n)}{|x|/n}  $$

Now let $n\rightarrow \infty$ (keeping $x\neq 0$ fixed).
By the properties of the function $\Delta$, the first and the last
terms on the RHS goes to zero and
as the LHS is independent of $n$ we deduce:
$$\left|\frac{e^x-(1+x+x^2/2)}{x^2} \right| \leq 
 (1+L(|x|)) \frac{\Delta(|x|)}{|x|}  .
$$
The RHS goes to zero as $|x|$ goes to zero,
and this implies the stated
limit.

Remark: Incidentally one may use the same telescopic procedure,
i.e. without binomial expansion,
to show that for $x$ fixed,
$e^x - (1+\frac{x}{n})^n \rightarrow 0$ as $n\rightarrow \infty$.

Answer (score 0):

Consider fundamental limit: $e = \lim\limits_{n\to \infty}(1+\frac{1}{n})^n$ and $e^x = \lim\limits_{n\to\infty}(1+\frac{x}{n})^n$

*Proof*

$e^x = [\lim\limits_{k\to\infty}(1+1/k)^k]^x = \lim\limits_{k\to \infty}((1+1/k)^{kx})\Rightarrow kx = n
\Rightarrow e^x = \lim\limits_{n\to\infty}(1+\frac{x}{n})^n$.

Understand the first expression:

$P = \large\frac{e^x-1}{x}$

Note that $e^x - 1 - x = x.[\large\frac{(e^x-1)}{x} - 1]\,\,\therefore\,\,$ $\boxed{\lim\limits_{x\to 0}\frac{e^x-1-x}{x^2}=\lim\limits_{x\to 0}\frac{P-1}{x}}$

Lets go to understand the expression $\,\,P-1$.

$P - 1= \frac{e^x - 1}{x} - 1 = \lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\left(\large\frac{[(1+\frac{x}{n})^n - 1]}{x} - 1\right)=$

Using that **tool**:

$\boxed{b^n - 1 = (b-1).(b^{n-1}+b^{n-2}+...+1)}$

$=\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\left((1+\frac{x}{n}-1).\large\frac{[(1+x/n)^{n-1} + (1+x/n)^{n-2} + ... + {1+x/n}]}{x}-1 \right) =\\
\\
= \lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\left(\frac{1}{n}.[(1+x/n)^{n-1} + (1+x/n)^{n-2} + ... + (1+x/n)]-1\right) = \\
\\
=\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\frac{1}{n}.\left((1+x/n)^{n-1} + (1+x/n)^{n-2} + ... + (1+x/n)-n\right)$

Writing the last "$n$" as $\underbrace{1+1+1...+1}_{n\,\, times}$ and inputing these $1`s$ into it:

$P-1 = \lim\limits_{n\to\infty} (1/n).[((1+x/n)^{n-1} - 1)+ ((1+x/n)^{n-2} - 1) + ... + ((1+x/n) - 1)]$

Using again that tool in **each** expression:

$=\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}(\frac{1}{n}).(\frac{x}{n}) [((1+x/n)^{n-2} + (1+x/n)^{n-3} + ... +1)+((1+x/n)^{n-3}+...+1)+...+1]$

Finally,

$L = \lim\limits_{x\to 0}\frac{P-1}{x} =\lim\limits_{x\to 0}\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}(\frac{1}{n}).(\frac{x}{n})[\large\frac{((1+x/n)^{n-2} + (1+x/n)^{n-3} + ... + 1 ) + ( (1+x/n)^{n-3} + ... + 1 ) + ... + 1)}{x}]=$

$=\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\lim\limits_{x\to0}(\frac{1}{n}).(\frac{x}{n})[\large\frac{((1+x/n)^{n-2} + (1+x/n)^{n-3} + ... + 1 ) + ( (1+x/n)^{n-3} + ... + 1 ) + ... + 1)}{x}] =\\$

$=\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\lim\limits_{x\to 0}\left(\frac{1}{n^2}\right).((1+x/n)^{n-2} + (1+x/n)^{n-3} + ... + 1 ) + ( (1+x/n)^{n-3} + ... + 1 ) + ... + 1) =$

$=\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\left(\frac{1}{n^2}\right)(n-1 + n-2 + n-3 + ... + 1) = \lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\left(\frac{1}{n^2}\right)(n-1)(\frac{n}{2}) = \lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\frac{n-1}{2n} = \boxed{\large\frac{1}{2}}$.

Answer (score 0):

$$
\displaylines{
  \mathop {\lim }\limits_{_{x \to 0} } \frac{{e^x  - x - 1}}{{x^2 }} = \frac{1}{4}\mathop {\lim }\limits_{_{t \to 0} } \frac{{e^{2t}  - 2t - 1}}{{t^2 }} \cr 
   = \frac{1}{4}\mathop {\lim }\limits_{_{t \to 0} } \frac{{e^{2t}  - 2e^t  + 1 - 1 - 2t - 1}}{{t^2 }} \cr 
   = \frac{1}{4}\mathop {\lim }\limits_{_{t \to 0} } \frac{{e^{2t}  - 2e^t  + 1}}{{t^2 }} - 2\mathop {\lim }\limits_{_{t \to 0} } \frac{{e^t  - t - 1}}{{t^2 }} \cr 
  \mathop {\lim }\limits_{_{x \to 0} } \frac{{e^x  - x - 1}}{{x^2 }} = \frac{1}{2} \cdots \left( 1 \right) \cr}
$$

$$
m = \frac{1}{4}\mathop {\lim }\limits_{_{t \to 0} } \frac{{e^{2t}  - 2e^t  + 1}}{{t^2 }} - 2m \Leftrightarrow m = \frac{1}{2}
$$

Comment: Why should the limit exist?

Comment: Why the additional $-2e^t$ on the second line?