# Determine $\lim_{x \to 0}{\frac{x-\sin{x}}{x^3}}=\frac{1}{6}$, without L'Hospital or Taylor

Tags: calculus, limits, limits-without-lhopital

How can I prove that $$\lim_{x \to 0}{\frac{x-\sin{x}}{x^3}}=\frac{1}{6}$$

without using L'Hospital or Taylor series?

thanks :)

Comment: Use Taylor expansion.

Comment: Epsilon-Delta argument...have fun with that one.

Comment: ... without the Axiom of Choice, without using the letter 'a', without a net...

Comment: GH Hardy "Pure Mathematics" Examples XLVI (page 237 in Tenth Edition) has some nice exercises starting with $x-\sin x$ and $\tan x-x$ are increasing for suitable small positive $x$

Comment: Why (-1) downvoter ?

Comment: @Iuli Perhaps because the question was changed to exclude a possibility after an answer was given - which was, I think, intended to invite alternative answers, but misguided (rude) as a way of doing so. The person who put the answer has had to amend it to explain why it was given. Instead you might have put - "there is a nice Taylor Series answer already, but I'm also looking for other ideas and ways of attacking this problem". I was not the down voter.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Evaluation of $\lim\limits\_{x\rightarrow0} \frac{\tan(x)-x}{x^3}$](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/157903/evaluation-of-lim-limits-x-rightarrow0-frac-tanx-xx3)

Comment: See in particular this answer, which also covers the case with $\sin$ instead of $\tan$: http://math.stackexchange.com/a/158134/1242

Comment: Instead of asking for no L'Hôpital or no Taylor Series, it would probably be better to ask for a pre-calculus proof and apply the [tag:algebra-precalculus] tag.

Answer (score 54, accepted):

Let $L = \lim_{x \to 0} \dfrac{x - \sin(x)}{x^3}$. We then have
\begin{align}
L & = \underbrace{\lim_{y \to 0} \dfrac{3y - \sin(3y)}{27y^3} = \lim_{y \to 0} \dfrac{3y - 3\sin(y) + 4 \sin^3(y)}{27y^3}}_{\sin(3y) = 3 \sin(y) - 4 \sin^3(y)}\\
& = \lim_{y \to 0} \dfrac{3y - 3\sin(y)}{27 y^3} + \dfrac4{27} \lim_{y \to 0} \dfrac{\sin^3(y)}{y^3} = \dfrac{3}{27} L + \dfrac4{27}
\end{align}
This gives us $24L = 4 \implies L = \dfrac16$

Comment: Thanks for ending this madness :D.

Comment: Dont you need first to prove that the limit exists? For example $\lim_ {x \rightarrow \infty} \cos (x)=\lim_ {x \rightarrow \infty} \cos (2x)=\lim_ {x \rightarrow \infty} \cos (x) ^2-1\Rightarrow a=2a^2-1$ and solve

Comment: How do you show that the $\lim$ exists in the firs place?

Comment: Yes, that is a good point. Let me think of a method to prove that limit exists and then add it to the post.

Comment: It exists by l'Hopital's rule, or the Taylor expansion.  :)  Seriously, though, assuming you can prove the existing somewhere, that is a really great idea I would never have thought of.

Comment: @Graphth Yes. That was the only way that came to my mind to prove the existence of the limit :)

Comment: This is somewhat similar to [this question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/184053/how-to-find-lim-limits-x-to0-fracex-1-xx2-without-using-lhopitals-r/184245#184245) (and answer) of mine (which didn't get so much upvotes).

Comment: @enzotib Don't worry about up-votes. The voting, to the most part, is at best random on this website. So no point losing sleep over it. I have +1ed your answer :)

Comment: Oh yes, sometimes some good questions pass over heads for unpredictable reasons, having posted on Sunday or similar.

Comment: We are waiting the proof of the existence of the limit. (Without l'Hopital's rule, or the Taylor expansion, finite or infinite :-)  )

Comment: See this: http://math.stackexchange.com/a/158134/1242

Comment: @HansLundmark Thanks. Instead of closing this question, I would suggest to paste your proof of $\dfrac{x - \sin(x)}{x^3}$ here, since the other question asks for $\dfrac{x - \tan(x)}{x^3}$.

Comment: Well, then both the question *and* the answer would be duplicated, so I think a link is enough... ;-)

Comment: @HansLundmark Thanks for the link. In that page there are a lot of interesting proofs.

Answer (score 13):

**Note:** The original question didn't say anything about not using Taylor series.  Then, after I answered this, the OP changed the question and said didn't want Taylor series either.

Another option would be using power series (aka Maclaurin series aka Taylor series centered at 0)

$$\sin x = x - \frac{x^3}{3!} + \frac{x^5}{5!} - \cdots$$

At this point, it's pretty easy.

Comment: yes, yes . another method ?

Comment: This is the definition of $\sin$, so I any other method would necessarily be derived from this.

Comment: yes, I have agree with you. I forgot to mention it.

Comment: @IHaveAStupidQuestion That is **one** definition of $\sin$. There are others.

Comment: @Peter But this is the one normally done in introductory calculus courses and the most natural one.

Comment: @IHaveAStupidQuestion I was taught that $\sin$ was defined as $$\sin := \frac{\text {Opposite}}{\text{Hypotenuse}}$$  Abramowitz and Stegun define $$\sin x := \frac{e^{i x}-e^{- i x}}{2}$$  One may also define $\sin$ as a solution to a differential equation.  Many possible definitions exist.

Comment: @Argon The first definition is the one used in high school. The second definition is literally the same as the Taylor expansion by using the definition of exp.

Comment: You could make up arbitrarily many nice formulas that are equal to $sin(x)$. I think this discussion is pointless.

Comment: @IHaveAStupidQuestion But clearly there exist many nice definitions for sine!

Comment: Totally agreed. But you will agree that using the Taylor series/exponential function is the most canonical and most frequently used. You said it yourself, its even in Abramowitz/Stegun.

Comment: Why did you delete the cool continued fraction? :D

Comment: @IHaveAStupidQuestion The fraction was big and somewhat unnecessary. However, I also point out that $\sin$ was known before the series was!

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/6183/discussion-between-ihaveastupidquestion-and-argon)

Answer (score 9):

Short answer: function discussion.
Long answer (details) is here.

First step. 
Your fraction is an even function so it is enough to consider the right limit.

Second step.
Define the functions $f(x):=\sin(x)-x+\frac{1}{6}x^3$ and $g(x):=\sin(x)-x+\frac{1}{6}x^3-\frac{1}{120}x^5$ on the interval $[0, 0.1]$.

Third step. Prove that $f$ is strictly increasing and $g$ is strictly decreasing. ($f(0)=0$, it is enough $f'>0$. $f'(0)=0$, so it is enough $f''>0$ and so on. Similarly for $g$.

Forth step. From the third step 
$$
x-\frac{1}{6}x^3<\sin(x)<x-\frac{1}{6}x^3+\frac{1}{120}x^5.
$$
The limit follows.

Answer (score 6):

Assuming $f$ is sufficiently smooth, repeated application of the fundamental theorem of the calculus gives (finite Taylor expansion)
$$f(x) = f(0)+f'(0)x+\frac{f''(0)}{2!}x^2 + \frac{f'''(0)}{3!}x^3 + \int_0^x (x-t)^2 \frac{(f'''(t)-f'''(0))}{2!}\, dt$$

Using the fact that $\sin' = \cos, \cos' = -\sin$, we can then expand $f(x) = \sin x$ as
$$ \sin x = x -\frac{x^3}{6} + \int_0^x (x-t)^2 \frac{(-\cos t +1)}{2!}\, dt$$
Let $\epsilon>0$, and choose $\delta>0$ such that if $|t|< \delta$, then $|1-\cos t| < \epsilon$. Then, replacing $1-\cos t$ by $\epsilon$ and integrating, we have the estimate
$$ \left|\sin x - x + \frac{x^3}{6} \right|  \leq \epsilon \frac{|x|^3}{6}$$
If $0 < |x| < \delta$, then dividing through by $|x^3|$ gives:
$$ \left| \frac{\sin x - x}{x^3} +\frac{1}{6} \right|  \leq \frac{\epsilon}{6} < \epsilon$$
The desired limit follows.

Answer (score 5):

First, an identity. For $x\ne0$,
$$
\begin{align}
\frac{2\sin(x)-\sin(2x)}{x^3}
&=\frac{2\sin(x)-2\sin(x)\cos(x)}{x^3}\tag{1a}\\
&=2\frac{\sin(x)}x\frac{1-\cos(x)}{x^2}\tag{1b}\\
&=\frac2{1+\cos(x)}\frac{\sin^3(x)}{x^3}\tag{1c}
\end{align}
$$
Explanation:
$\text{(1a)}$: $\sin(2x)=2\sin(x)\cos(x)$
$\text{(1b)}$: algebra
$\text{(1c)}$: $1-\cos(x)=\frac{\sin^2(x)}{1+\cos(x)}$

In [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/75151), it is shown geometrically that $\lim\limits_{x\to0}\frac{\sin(x)}x=1$. Thus, given $\epsilon\gt0$, we can choose $\delta\gt0$ so that if $0\lt|x|\le\delta$, then
$$
\frac2{1+\cos(x)}\frac{\sin^3(x)}{x^3}=[1-\epsilon,1+\epsilon]_\#\tag2
$$
where $[a,b]_\#$ is a real number in the interval $[a,b]$.

For $0\lt|x|\le\delta$, apply $(1)$ and $(2)$ to $x/2^{k+1}$ and divide by $2^{2k+3}$:
$$
\frac{2^{k+1}\sin\left(x/2^{k+1}\right)-2^k\sin\left(x/2^k\right)}{x^3}=\frac{[1-\epsilon,1+\epsilon]_\#}{2^{2k+3}}\tag3
$$
$\lim\limits_{x\to0}\frac{\sin(x)}x=1$ implies $\lim\limits_{k\to\infty}2^k\sin\left(x/2^k\right)=x$. Thus, if we sum $(3)$ in $k$, we get that for $0\lt|x|\le\delta$,
$$
\frac{x-\sin(x)}{x^3}=\frac{[1-\epsilon,1+\epsilon]_\#}6\tag4
$$
Therefore, the [Squeeze Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Squeeze_theorem) yields
$$
\lim_{x\to0}\frac{x-\sin(x)}{x^3}=\frac16\tag5
$$

Answer (score 2):

The following argument is based on the suggestions by vesszabo.  (I do not restrict the functions to the interval $[0, \, 0.1]$ as vesszabo did. That would erroneous because we are looking for the limit at $0$.)  It is a rigorous argument and it does avoid using Taylor's Theorem ... but it is still hokey.  The choice to use the functions $f$ and $g$ is guided by Taylor's Theorem.

**Demonstration**

$f$ is a function defined by
\begin{equation*}
f(x) = \sin{x} - x + \frac{1}{6} \, x^{3} .
\end{equation*}
This function is differentiable, and
\begin{equation*}
f^{\prime}(x) = \cos{x} - 1 + \frac{1}{2} \, x^{2} .
\end{equation*}
Likewise, this derivative is differentiable, and
\begin{equation*}
f^{\prime\prime}(x) = -\sin{x} + x .
\end{equation*}
$f(0) = f^{\prime}(0) = 0$, but since $f^{\prime\prime}(x) > 0$ for every positive, real number $x$, $f^{\prime}(x)$ is an increasing function, and since $f^{\prime}(0) = 0$, $f^{\prime}(x) > 0$ for every positive, real number $x$. According to a corollary to the Mean Value Theorem, $f$ is an increasing function. $f(0) = 0$, and so $f(x) > 0$ for every positive, real number $x$.

$g$ is another twice-differentiable function defined by
\begin{equation*}
g(x) = \sin{x} - x + \frac{1}{6} \, x^{3} - \frac{1}{120} x^{5} = f(x) - \frac{1}{120} x^{5} .
\end{equation*}
For every positive, real number $x$,
\begin{equation*}
g^{\prime\prime}(x)
= f^{\prime\prime}(x) - \frac{1}{6} x^{3}
= - f(x)
< 0 .
\end{equation*}
According to a corollary to the Mean Value Theorem, $g^{\prime}$ is a decreasing function. $g^{\prime}(0) = 0$, and so $g^{\prime}(x) < 0$ for every positive, real number $x$. According to a corollary to the Mean Value Theorem, $g$ is a decreasing function. $g(0) = 0$, and so $g(x) < 0$ for every positive, real number $x$.

So, for every positive, real number $x$,
\begin{equation*}
\frac{1}{6} \, x^{3} - \frac{1}{120} x^{5}
< x - \sin{x}
< \frac{1}{6} \, x^{3} ,
\end{equation*}
and
\begin{equation*}
\frac{1}{6} - \frac{1}{120} x^{2}
< \frac{x - \sin{x}}{x^{3}}
< \frac{1}{6} .
\end{equation*}
According to the Squeeze Theorem,
\begin{equation*}
\lim_{x\to0^{+}} \frac{x - \sin{x}}{x^{3}} = \frac{1}{6} .
\end{equation*}

$f$ and $g$ are odd functions. So, for every negative, real number $x$,
\begin{equation*}
\frac{1}{6} \, x^{3}
< x - \sin{x}
< \frac{1}{6} \, x^{3} - \frac{1}{120} x^{5} ,
\end{equation*}
and
\begin{equation*}
\frac{1}{6} - \frac{1}{120} x^{2}
< \frac{x - \sin{x}}{x^{3}}
< \frac{1}{6} .
\end{equation*}
Again, according to the Squeeze Theorem,
\begin{equation*}
\lim_{x\to0^{-}} \frac{x - \sin{x}}{x^{3}} = \frac{1}{6} .
\end{equation*}
A function that has the same left-sided and right-sided limits at $0$ has a limit at $0$.
\begin{equation*}
\lim_{x\to0} \frac{x - \sin{x}}{x^{3}} = \frac{1}{6} .
\end{equation*}