# How to find this limit?

Tags: calculus

I have the limit $$\lim_{x\to0}\frac{\pi/2-\arccos{(x^2)}-x^2}{x^6}.$$ Can somebody please explain to me why this limit exists (according to wolfram alpha it is $1/6$)? Using the standard properties for limits can I not reason that the limit is equal to $$\frac{\pi/2-\lim_{x\to0}\arccos{(x^2)}-\lim_{x\to0}x^2}{\lim_{x\to0}x^6}=\frac{\pi/2-\pi/2-\lim_{x\to0}x^2}{\lim_{x\to0}x^6}=\lim_{x\to0}\frac{-1}{x^4}$$ which is infinity/does not exist. Where exactly is the flaw in my reasoning?

Thanks

Comment: How did you happen to get $\,1\,$ in the numerator??

Comment: You will find the Taylor expansion of $\arccos(x)$ at $0$ here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taylor_series. Then substitute $x^2$ for $x$. You don't need to go further than $x^6$, provided you observe the remainder is $O(x^8)$.

Comment: Sorry, I meant -1... The $\pi/2$s cancel and I am left with $$\lim_{x\to0}\frac{-x^2}{x^6}$$. Then if I cancel the numerator I am left with $-1/x^4$. Right?

Comment: I know that I can use the Maclaurin series, but can you please tell me what's wrong with my reasoning above?

Comment: The only thing that your reasoning can prove is that the limit is undetermined of the form $0/0$.

Comment: But why is it of the form 0/0 if the numerator cancels?

Comment: At least one reason for your reasoning being wrong is that you are not allowed to take the limits of the denominator and numerator separately.

Comment: Here (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Limit_of_a_function#Properties) it says that I can.

Comment: As malin said, the only case where you can say for sure that $\lim f/g=\lim f/\lim g$ is when $\lim g\neq 0$.

Comment: Yes, and if you read carefully: "provided the limits on the right sides of the equations below exist (the last identity only holds if the denominator is non-zero)".

Comment: Here is another example: $\frac{(1+x^2+x^4)-1-x^2}{x^4}$. Applying your reasoning, the limit of the numerator at $0$ is $\lim(1+x^2+x^4)-\lim 1 -\lim x^2=1-1-\lim x^2=-\lim x^2$. Then you would cancel and say that $\lim -x^2/x^4=-\lim 1/x^2=-\infty$. Unfortunately, the numerator equals $x^4$, so the function equals $x^4/x^4=1$ for $x\neq 0$, so the limit is $1$.

Comment: Yes, I understand. Thanks!

Comment: Great! So now you see that you have no choice but MacLaurin expand up to $x^6$ with remainder $O(x^8)$. Unless there is some trick I have not noticed.

Comment: Yes. Actually, the exercise asks me right before to find the expansion (and that's how I solved it). But then I was wondering...

Answer (score 5):

(1)Let $\arcsin x^2=y\implies x^2=\sin y$ and $\arccos x^2=\frac\pi2- y$

$$\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{\frac{\pi}2 -\arccos x^2-x^2}{x^6}=\lim_{y\to0}\frac{y-\sin y}{\sin^3y}$$

(2)Alternatively, let $\arccos x^2=y\implies x=\cos y$ and as $x\to0,y=\arccos x^2\to\frac\pi2$

$$\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{\frac{\pi}2 -\arccos x^2-x^2}{x^6}$$

$$=\lim_{y\to \frac\pi2}\frac{\frac\pi2-y-\cos y}{\cos^3y}$$

$$=\lim_{z\to 0}\frac{z-\sin z}{\sin^3z} $$ (Putting  $ z=\frac\pi2-y,y\to\frac\pi2\implies z\to0,\cos y=\cos\left(\frac\pi2-z\right)=\sin z)$

Now $$\lim_{y\to 0}\frac{y-\sin y}{\sin^3y}$$
$$=\lim_{y\to 0}\frac{y-(y-\frac{y^3}{3!}+\frac{y^5}{5!}-\cdots)}{y^3}\left(\frac{y}{\sin y}\right)^3$$
$$=\lim_{y\to 0}\frac{(\frac{y^3}{3!}-\frac{y^5}{5!}+\cdots)}{y^3} \text { as  } \lim_{t\to0}\frac {\sin t}t=1$$
$$=\frac16$$

As $$\lim_{z\to 0}\frac{z-\sin z}{\sin^3z} \text {is of the form }\frac00$$ the problem can also be handled using L'Hospital Rule as follows:

$$\lim_{z\to 0}\frac{z-\sin z}{\sin^3z}$$
$$=\lim_{z\to 0}\frac{1-\cos z}{3\sin^2z\cos z} \text {which is again of the form }\frac00$$
$$=\lim_{z\to 0}\frac{\sin z}{-3\sin^3z+3\cos z2\sin z\cos z} \text {which is again of the form }\frac00$$
$$=\lim_{z\to 0}\frac{1}{-3\sin^2z+6\cos^2z}\text{ as } z\to0\implies z\ne0\implies \sin z\ne0 $$
$$=\frac16$$

Answer (score 1):

There is a shorter proof is you notice that $\arccos x^2$ can be expanded in Taylor series as $x \to 0: \ \arccos x^2 = \frac{\pi}{2}-x^2-\frac{x^6}{6} + O(x^{10})$. Then the constant and $x^2$ in the numerator cancel out and you remain with

$$
\lim_{x \to 0} \frac{x^6 + O(x^{10})}{6 x^6}=\frac{1}{6}
$$

Comment: Way to go, Alex!

Answer (score 0):

First recall that $\dfrac{\pi}2 - \arccos(y) = \arcsin(y)$. Hence, the limit you want to evaluate is
$$L = \lim_{x \to 0} \dfrac{\arcsin(x^2) - x^2}{x^6} = \lim_{t \to 0} \dfrac{t-\sin(t)}{\sin^3(t)} = \lim_{t \to 0} \dfrac{t-\sin(t)}{t^3} \lim_{t \to 0} \left(\dfrac{t}{\sin(t)} \right)^3 = \dfrac16 \times 1 = \dfrac16$$
where [$\lim_{t \to 0} \dfrac{t-\sin(t)}{t^3} = \dfrac16$ is proved here.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/217081/determine-lim-x-to-0-fracx-sinxx3-frac16-without-lhospita/217086#217086)