# Prove that $\lim_{x \to 0} \frac{x - \sin x}{x^3} = \frac16$ using notable limits

Tags: limits, alternative-proof

Can we prove that $\lim_{x \to 0} \frac{x - \sin x}{x^3} = \frac 16$ using just algebra, trigonometric theorems and notable limits $\left( \mathrm{i.e. }\quad \frac{\sin x}{x} \to 1 \quad \mathrm{and} \quad \frac{1 - \cos x}{x^2} \to \frac 12 \right) $ and no *l'Hospital rule*, no series expansion, no *Taylor series*?

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/217081/determine-lim-x-to-0-fracx-sinxx3-frac16-without-lhospita?rq=1

Comment: More in general refer to [Are all limits solvable without L'Hôpital Rule or Series Expansion](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/387333/505767)

Answer (score 1):

$\sin x=\sin (x/3)\cos(2x/3)+\cos(x/3)\sin(2x/3)=\sin (x/3)(1-2\sin^2(2x/3))+2\cos^2(x/3)\sin(x/3)=\sin (x/3)-2\sin^3 (x/3)+2\sin (x/3)-2\sin^3 (x/3)=3\sin (x/3)-4\sin^3 (x/3)$

$\frac{x-\sin x}{x^3}=\frac{x-3\sin (x/3)-4\sin^3 (x/3)}{x^3}=\frac{x-3\sin (x/3)}{x^3}-\frac{4\sin^3 (x/3)}{x^3}=1/9\frac{x/3-\sin (x/3)}{(x/3)^3}-4/27 \frac{\sin^3 (x/3)}{(x/3)^3}$

$m=\lim_{x\rightarrow 0} \frac{x-\sin x}{x^3}= 1/9\lim_{x\rightarrow 0}\frac{x/3-\sin (x/3)}{(x/3)^3}-4/27\lim_{x\rightarrow 0} \frac{\sin^3 (x/3)}{(x/3)^3}=1/9M-4/27 \Rightarrow 8/9M=4/27\Rightarrow M=1/6.$

Comment: This is a really nifty way to compute the limit, but it assumes the limit exists.

Comment: Yes, that's correct.