# Problem about convergent series

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits, number-comparison

I'm trying to prove this series converges by using some sort of comparison test.

> $$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n^{0.51}}-\sin\left(\frac{1}{n^{0.51}}\right)$$

I know by $\sin n\le n$ that the series is positive, so I went with the direction of using the comparison test.
But I can't seem to find a function that is always greater than the expression in the series that also converges..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the fact that for $x \geq 0$,
$$x - \sin(x) \leq \frac{1}{6} x^3.$$

Comment: How would one prove such a claim?

Comment: @MathCurious Show that $f(x) = \frac16 x^3 - x + \sin x \ge 0$

Comment: So how do you prove that the RHS function converges?

Comment: @Ritam_Dasgupta are you asking about the convegence of the series $\sum \frac{1}{n^{1.53}}$ ?

Comment: Yes, that is what I'm asking

Comment: @Ritam_Dasgupta it is a classical result that the series $\sum \frac{1}{n^s}$ converges if and only if $s > 1$. It can be shown (for example) with a comparison with an integral.

Comment: This is related to Riemann's zeta function, isn't it?

Comment: @MathCurious: [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3718781) gives a pre-calculus proof that $\lim\limits_{x\to0}\frac{x-\sin(x)}{x^3}=\frac16$.

Answer (score 3):

Using the Taylor series for $\sin x$, we have
$$\sin \frac{1}{n^p} = \frac{1}{n^p} + O\left(\frac{1}{n^{2p}}\right)$$
Therefore
$$S=\sum_{n\ge 1}\frac{1}{n^p} - \sin \frac{1}{n^p} = \sum_{n\ge 1}\frac{1}{n^p} - \frac{1}{n^p} + O\left(\frac{1}{n^{2p}}\right) = \sum_{n\ge 1}O\left(\frac{1}{n^{2p}}\right)$$
Hence, the series $S$ converges if $p > 0.5$.

Your series converges since $0.51 > 0.5$.

Comment: Hi thanks for the response! We haven't gone through Taylor Series yet unfortunately. :(

Comment: The series converges iff $p\gt\frac13$. What you've shown is that the series converges **if** $p\gt\frac12$.

Answer (score 1):

Using Heine's definition for limits at $\infty$ and using the limit comparison test with $\;b_n=\frac{1}{6\left(n^{0.51}\right)^{3}}=\frac{1}{6n^{1.53}}$ , we get:

$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{\frac{1}{n^{0.51}}-\sin\left(\frac{1}{n^{0.51}}\right)}{\frac{1}{6n^{1.53}}}{=}\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{\frac{1}{x^{0.51}}-\sin\left(\frac{1}{x^{0.51}}\right)}{\frac{1}{6x^{1.53}}}\underset{t=\frac{1}{x^{0.51}}}{=}\lim_{t\to0^{+}}\frac{t-\sin t}{\frac{t^{3}}{6}}\underset{L}{=}$$
$$\lim_{t\to0^{+}}\frac{1-\cos t}{\frac{t^{2}}{2}}\underset{L}{=}\lim_{t\to0^{+}}\frac{\sin t}{t}=1$$
Hence $\displaystyle{\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\left[\frac{1}{n^{0.51}}-\sin\left(\frac{1}{n^{0.51}}\right)\right]}$ converges with $\displaystyle{{\displaystyle \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}b_{n}}}$.