# Find $\lim_{{x \to 0}} \frac{x - \sin x}{x - \tan x}$ without using L'Hôpital's rule

Tags: calculus, limits, limits-without-lhopital

I'm trying to find this limit:

$$\lim_{{x \to 0}} \frac{x - \sin x}{x - \tan x}$$

I want to use only algebraic manipulations and trigonometric identities, without L'Hôpital's rule or Taylor series.

I tried to use all the identities I know but I couldn't get rid of the indeterminate form.

Comment: have a look here https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/217081/determine-lim-x-to-0-fracx-sinxx3-frac16-without-lhospita

Answer (score 4):

Using [Determine $\lim_{x \to 0}{\frac{x-\sin{x}}{x^3}}=\frac{1}{6}$, without L'Hospital or Taylor](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/217081/determine-lim-x-to-0-fracx-sinxx3-frac16-without-lhospita), one has
$$ \begin{eqnarray}
&&\lim_{x\to0}\frac{x-\tan x}{x^3}\\
&=&\lim_{x\to0}\frac1{\cos x}\frac{(x\cos x-x)+(x-\sin x)}{x^3}\\
&=&\lim_{x\to0}\frac1{\cos x}\bigg(\frac{\cos x-1}{x^2}+\frac{x-\sin x}{x^3}\bigg) \\
&=&\lim_{x\to0}\frac1{\cos x}\bigg(\frac{x-\sin x}{x^3}-\frac{2\sin^2(\frac x2)}{x^2}\bigg) \\
&=&\frac16-\frac12=-\frac13
\end{eqnarray} $$
and hence

$$ \lim_{{x \to 0}} \frac{x - \sin x}{x - \tan x}=\lim_{{x \to 0}} \frac{x - \sin x}{x^3}\cdot\frac{x^3}{x - \tan x}=\frac16(-3)=-\frac12.$$$

Comment: (+1) All to easy ... ;-))

Comment: @MarkViola, thank you.

Comment: Use the series expansions of $sin(x)$ and $tan(x)$. I think it will help.

Answer (score 2):

According to your question, we have to find $$\lim_{x\to0} \frac{x-\sin(x)}{x-\tan(x)}$$. Now the series expansion of $\sin(x)$ is $x-\frac{x^{3}}{3!}+\frac{x^{5}}{5!}-...$ and the series expansion of $\tan(x)$ is $x+\frac{x^{3}}{3}+\frac{2x^{5}}{15}+...$
Now just put the series expansion of $\sin(x)$ and $\tan(x)$ to find the value of the above limit. So, you will get $$\lim_{x\to0} \frac{x-(x-\frac{x^{3}}{3!}+\frac{x^{5}}{5!}-...)}{x-(x+\frac{x^{3}}{3}+\frac{2x^{5}}{15}+...)}$$. Now take $\frac{x^{3}}{3!}$ common from the numerator and $\frac{-x^{3}}{3}$ common from the denominator. So, the final answer of your limits will be $\frac{-1}{2}$.

Comment: In my answer I have used the Maclaurian series expansions.

Comment: OP does specifically say ... without Taylor series

Comment: But mine is Maclaurian series.

Comment: Maclaurin Series are a special case of Taylor series!

Comment: Yes you are correct @BenjaminDickman.