# Finding the limit without using L'Hôpital's rule or a Taylor/Maclaurin series.

Tags: limits

Can this limit be found without using L'Hôpital's rule or Taylor/Maclaurin series?--
$$L=\displaystyle\lim_{x \rightarrow 0} \dfrac{e^x-x-1}{x^2}$$

I came up to the right answer..just that the method is not foolproof.

--

Let $L$ be the limit. So,

$$L=\lim_{x \rightarrow 0}\dfrac{e^x-x-1}{x^2}$$ Now, let $x=2y$. So, $$L=\lim_{x \rightarrow 0} \dfrac{e^{2y}-2y-1}{4y^2}$$So, the limit can be rewritten as $$L=\lim_{y \rightarrow 0} \dfrac{e^{2y}-2e^y+1+2e^y-2y-2}{4y^2}$$ which is $$L=\dfrac{1}{4}\lim_{y \rightarrow 0} \left(\left(\dfrac{e^y-1}{y}\right)^2+2\dfrac{e^y-y-1}{y^2}\right)$$ Now comes what i was saying. What i did was i separated the limit across the two terms. We can do that only if the two limits exist individually and finitely. The first, i am sure, exists.But notice the second term is twice the limit we desire to find. So, this method is only applicable when the limit exists.If we do substitute the second term with 2L, we have $$L=\dfrac{1}{4} (1+2L)=L$$ Solving for $L$ we get $\boxed{L=\dfrac{1}{2}}$.

But as I said this method is not foolproof. Is there any?

Comment: Related : http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/387333/are-all-limits-solvable-without-lhospital-rule-or-series-expansion

Comment: @labbhattacharjee I do have a solution..don't know if it's right..

Comment: Why don't you add that to the Question & get it verified?

Comment: Definitely show us your work @user157130

Comment: See also: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/184053/how-to-find-lim-limits-x-to0-fracex-1-xx2-without-using-lhopitals-r

Comment: @ThomasAndrews Check out the edit.

Comment: But how do you know the $(e^y-1)/y$ limit without l'Hopital and/or Maclaurin series?

Comment: @GerryMyerson There are many ways to prove that. [This](http://www.ies-math.com/math/java/calc/lim_e/lim_e.html) simplest i know.

Comment: At that link, they go from $t=e^x-1$ to $$1+{1\over t}=e^x$$ so I'm not sure I'd rely on what's there.

Comment: @GerryMyerson Can't we just use the fact that
$$\lim_{y\to 0}\frac{e^y-1}{y}=\lim_{y\to 0}\frac{e^{0+y}-e^0}{y-0}$$
is the derivative of $y\mapsto e^y$ at $y=0$ by definition and therefore equal to $e^0=1$? I don't see how that uses l'Hôpital or Maclaurin series. (This is directed at an earlier comment of yours.)

Comment: @Joffy, how do you prove that the derivative of $e^x$ is $e^x$, without first evaluating the limit, $\lim_{h\to0}(e^h-1)/h$?

Comment: @GerryMyerson How to prove that depends on the definition of $e$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can use squeeze theorem .

For, $x$ sufficiently close to $0$ , following identity holds true:

$$ 1+x+\frac{x^2}{2}+x^3 \ge e^x \ge 1+x+\frac{x^2}{2}$$

These holds good, too but  i have proved LHS part using taylor expansion, which is a crime to use in this problem. Any proof of LHS part, without expansion will do the work.