# $\lim_{x\to0}\frac{e^x-1-x}{x^2}$ using only rules of algebra of limits.

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, limits, contest-math, limits-without-lhopital

I would like to solve that limit  solved using only **rules of algebra of limits**.

$$\lim_{x\to0}\frac{e^x-1-x}{x^2}$$

All the answers in [How to find $\lim\limits_{x\to0}\frac{e^x-1-x}{x^2}$ without using l'Hopital's rule nor any series expansion?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/184053/how-to-find-lim-limits-x-to0-fracex-1-xx2-without-using-lhopitals-r) do not fully address my question.

A challenging limit problem for the level of student who knows that:
$$\begin{align*}
\lim\limits_{x\to +\infty} e^x&=+\infty\tag1\\
\lim\limits_{x\to -\infty} e^x&=0\tag2\\
\lim\limits_{x\to +\infty} \frac{e^x}{x^n}&=+\infty\tag3\\
\lim\limits_{x\to -\infty} x^ne^x&=0\tag4\\
\lim\limits_{x\to 0} \frac{e^x-1}{x}&=1\tag5
\end{align*}$$

Comment: you need $\epsilon-\delta$ stuff?

Comment: no because the level of student doesn't support that kind of stuff

Comment: Why does the last answer (the 25 + yes answer) not address your question?  What about it does not help/work for you?

Comment: as i said before the level of students does'nt support the level using in that answer

Comment: can one use the definition of $e$ as a limit?

Comment: Unfortunately we can't use it

Comment: We have to know what definition of $e^x$ to use...

Comment: @paw88789 No, that's the derivative of $e^x$ at $0$.

Comment: The last limit was different when I looked before, with $x\to-\infty$ of the same expression that now has $x\to 0$.  List looks fine now.

Comment: The correct approach might be to forget limits and instead to write a few inequalities that squeeze the expression to $1/2$. I wonder if we can use $x+1 \leq e^x$.

Comment: yes u can use it but i don't know how u can use that without over the level of the student

Comment: Ok. Is answer $0$?

Comment: nope $\frac{1}{2}$

Comment: Having that $1+x+\frac {x^2} 2$ bounds $e^x$ from below on the left and from above on the right would be trivially sufficient. However, the properties you've listed do not uniquely identify $e^x$. They could be satisfied by a different function with a different second derivative at 0, so you'll find no answer.

Comment: can we use $e^{a+b} = e^a e^b?$

Comment: yes of course you can use it

Comment: Some answers below use the fact that the desired limit exists. Showing that the limit exists is tricky and not possible without the use of derivative (i.e. L'Hospital, Taylor or something equivalent). It is better to understand the powers of rules of algebra of limits but at the same time it is important to know their limitation.

Comment: @ParamanandSingh Another advantage to note is that series allows you to observe the rate at which the limit converges (or diverges)

Answer (score 23):

$$
\lim\limits_{x\to 0}\dfrac{e^x-1-x}{x^2} = \lim\limits_{x\to 0}\left(\dfrac{1}{e^x+1+x}\right)\lim\limits_{x\to 0}\dfrac{e^{2x}-(1+x)^2}{x^2} = \dfrac{1}{2}\lim\limits_{x\to 0}\left(4\dfrac{e^{2x}-1-2x}{4x^2}-1\right) = 2\lim\limits_{x\to 0}\left(\dfrac{e^{2x}-1-2x}{4x^2}\right)-\dfrac{1}{2} = 2\lim\limits_{x\to 0}\left(\dfrac{e^x-1-x}{x^2}\right)-\dfrac{1}{2}.
$$

Therefore,

> $$\lim\limits_{x\to 0}\dfrac{e^x-1-x}{x^2} = \dfrac{1}{2}\,.$$

---

This can be extended in a natural way. Define $s_{n}(x):=\sum\limits_{k=0}^{n-1}\dfrac{x^k}{k!}$ and observe the following:
$$
\begin{eqnarray*}
\lim_{x\to0}\dfrac{e^x-s_{n}(x)}{x^n} &=& \lim_{x\to0}\left(\dfrac{1}{\sum\limits_{r=0}^{n-1}e^{rx}(s_n(x))^{n-1-r}}\right)\lim_{x\to0}\dfrac{e^{nx}-(s_n(x))^n}{x^n} \\ &&\ \\ \ \\ &=& \dfrac{1}{n}\left(\lim_{x\to0}\dfrac{e^{nx}-s_n(nx)-\frac{n^{n-1}-1}{(n-1)!}x^n-o(x^n)}{x^n}\right)\\ &&\ \\ \ \\&=& 
n^{n-1}\lim_{x\to0}\left(\dfrac{e^{nx}-s_n(nx)}{(nx)^n}\right)-\frac{n^{n-1}-1}{n!}\,, 
\end{eqnarray*}
$$

where, upon expansion, the polynomial $(s_n(x))^n = s_n(nx) + \frac{n^{n-1}-1}{(n-1)!}x^n + o(x^n)$. Consequently,

> $$
> \lim_{x\to0}\dfrac{e^x-s_n(x)}{x^n} = \dfrac{1}{n!}\,.
> $$

---

The foregoing arguments require the existence of the primary limits being sought after. Given that our hypothetical pupil is not armed with sophisticated $\epsilon, \delta$ analysis techniques, it is difficult to see how he might proceed in showing existence. Indeed, how does this pupil even know what a limit is, let alone the algebraic laws that follow by definition? Nevertheless, with these concerns in mind, we might at least allow our student one more atom of information: the interchange of limits for the particular class of functions we are interested in here. Thus, our pupil proceeds, somewhat mechanistically, as follows:

$$
\begin{eqnarray*}
\lim\limits_{x\to 0}\frac{e^{x}-s_n(x)}{x^n} &=& \lim\limits_{x\to 0}\lim\limits_{y\to 0}\frac{\left(e^{y}(\frac{e^{x}-1}{x})-\frac{1}{x}\Big(s_n(x+y)-s_n(y)\Big)\right)}{\Big(\sum\limits_{r=0}^{n-1}(x+y)^r y^{n-1-r}\Big)} \\ &&\ \\&=& \lim\limits_{y\to 0}\lim\limits_{x\to 0}\frac{\left(e^{y}(\frac{e^{x}-1}{x})-\frac{1}{x}\Big(s_n(x+y)-s_n(y)\Big)\right)}{\Big(\sum\limits_{r=0}^{n-1}(x+y)^r y^{n-1-r}\Big)} \\ &&\ \\&=& \frac{1}{n}\lim\limits_{y\to 0}\frac{\left(e^{y}-s_{n-1}(y)\right)}{y^{n-1}}\,.
\end{eqnarray*}$$

So, by successive application of such interchanges, our pupil deduces

> $$
> \lim\limits_{x\to 0}\frac{e^{x}-s_n(x)}{x^n} = \frac{1}{n!}\,.
> $$

Comment: This is very interesting.  Can all the terms of the Taylor series of $e^x$ be done similarly?

Comment: I believe that you use here assumption that the limit exists. Can you show the existence of limit?

Comment: @GEdgar, please see edits.

Comment: @Wojowu, please see edits

Comment: What is it about "$e$" that make this work?  Why won't this work for $a^x$ also?  Is it because the first case $\lim (e^x-1)/x = 1$ is for $e$ only, and does not follow algebraically like the rest?

Comment: @GEdgar, An analogous development can be used for the function $a^x$, I suspect, where one specifies $\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{a^x-1}{x} = \log a$. Nothing special about $e^x$ or "$e$" in this sense. Of course, the functions $s_n(x)$ will need to be appropriately defined.

Comment: nice work. the conjugates. need to remember that.

Comment: Nice trick. Alas it only works if you know the limit exists.

Answer (score 9):

$$\left(\frac{e^x-1}x\right)^2=\frac{e^{2x}-2e^x+1}{x^2}=2^2\frac{e^{2x}-1-2x}{(2x)^2}-2\frac{e^x-1-x}{x^2}.$$

Then, taking the limit,

$$1=4L-2L.$$

---

UPDATE: the same approach can be used for the next order,

$$\left(\frac{e^x-1}x\right)^3=\frac{e^{3x}-3e^{2x}+3e^x-1}{x^3}=3^3f(3x)-3\cdot2^3(2x)+3f(x),$$
where $f(x)=\dfrac{e^x-1-x-\dfrac{x^2}2}{x^3},$
and
$$1=27L-24L+3L.$$

Comment: Just a shorter version than that of @ki3i.

Comment: I originally thought the question was kind of stupid.  But I see from these two answers that I was wrong.

Comment: @GEdgar: I was myself amazed and pleased to discover that the whole Taylor development can be derived from the initial limit.

Answer (score 2):

In order to show that

$$\lim_{x\to0}{e^x-1-x\over x^2}={1\over2}$$

it suffices to show that

$$\lim_{x\to0}{1\over x^2}\int_0^x(e^u-1-u)\,du=0$$

Let $g(u)=e^u-1-u$. Since $g'(u)=e^u-1$ and $g''(u)=e^u$, we see that $g(u)$ has a global minimum at $u=0$, with $g(0)=0$. Consequently

$$0\le{1\over x^2}\int_0^x(e^u-1-u)\,du\le{1\over x}\int_0^x{e^u-1-u\over u}\,du\quad\text{for }x\not=0$$

By the Mean Value Theorem,

$$\lim_{x\to0}{1\over x}\int_0^x{e^u-1-u\over u}\,du=\lim_{u\to0}{e^u-1-u\over u}$$

But

$$\lim_{u\to0}{e^u-1-u\over u}=\lim_{u\to0}{g(u)-g(0)\over u-0}=g'(0)=0$$

Thus, by the Squeeze Theorem, $\lim_{x\to0}{1\over x^2}\int_0^x(e^u-1-u)\,du=0$.

Answer (score 2):

Note that

$$e^x-1-x= \int_0^x (e^t-1)\, dt = \int_0^x \int_0^t e^s\,ds\, dt.$$

Now $1\le e^s \le e^x$ above. Thus $e^x-1-x$ lies between

$$\tag 1 \int_0^x \int_0^t 1 \,ds\, dt,\, \,\,\int_0^x \int_0^t e^x\,ds\, dt.$$

The first iterated integral in $(1)$ equals $x^2/2,$ the one on the right equals $e^x(x^2/2).$ So we have $e^x-1-x$ between $x^2/2$ and $e^x(x^2/2).$ Dividing by $x^2$ and using the squeeze theorem gives $1/2$ for the desired limit.

Comment: I managed to extend this method to the more general case, if you'd care to take a look.

Comment: (+1) for efficiency!  Happy Holidays my friend.  Hope you're doing well!

Comment: @MarkViola  MV, I haven't seen you in the longest! May the blessings of the season be with you.

Comment: @zhw. Thank you ZW!  And you.

Answer (score 2):

One could consider the more general limit:

$$L_n=\lim_{x\to0}x^{-n}(e^x-P_{n-1}(x))$$

where

$$P_n(x)=\sum_{k=0}^n\frac{x^k}{k!}$$

It may be easily seen that

$$e^x-P_n(x)=\int_0^xe^t-P_{n-1}(t)~\mathrm dt$$

And by induction,

$$e^x-P_{n-1}(x)=\int_0^x\int_0^{\sigma_n}\dots\int_0^{\sigma_2}e^{\sigma_1}~\mathrm d\sigma_1~\mathrm d\sigma_2\dots\mathrm d\sigma_n$$

By [Cauchy's repeated integral formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy_formula_for_repeated_integration), it can be seen that

$$e^x-P_{n-1}(x)=\frac1{(n-1)!}\int_0^x(x-t)^{n-1}e^t~\mathrm dt$$

And by substituting $t=xu$, this simplifies down to

$$e^x-P_{n-1}(x)=\frac{x^n}{(n-1)!}\int_0^1(1-u)^{n-1}e^{xu}~\mathrm du$$

Which so nicely cancels the $x^n$, and likewise, it is easy to see that

$$\int_0^1(1-u)^{n-1}e^{-|x|}~\mathrm du<\int_0^1(1-t)^{n-1}e^{xu}~\mathrm du<\int_0^1(1-u)^{n-1}e^{|x|}~\mathrm du$$

So by the squeeze theorem,

$$\begin{align}\lim_{x\to0}x^{-n}(e^x-P_{n-1}(x))&=\lim_{x\to0}\frac1{(n-1)!}\int_0^1(1-u)^{n-1}e^{xu}~\mathrm du\\&=\frac1{(n-1)!}\int_0^1(1-u)^{n-1}~\mathrm du\\&=\frac1{(n-1)!}\frac1n\\&=\frac1{n!}\end{align}$$

As expected.

Comment: This is effectively the Taylor's theorem with Cauchy's remainder applied on exponential function. +1

Answer (score 1):

$$\lim_{x\to0} \dfrac{e^x-1-x}{x^2}= \lim_{x\to0} \dfrac{e^{-x}-1+x}{x^2}= \lim_{x\to0} \dfrac{e^x+e^{-x}-2}{2x^2}=\displaystyle \dfrac{1}{2}  \lim_{x\to0} \Bigg(\dfrac{e^{\frac{x}{2}}-e^{\frac{-x}{2}}}{x}\Bigg)^2$$
$$=\displaystyle \dfrac{1}{2} \lim_{x\to0} \Bigg(\dfrac{e^{\frac{x}{2}}-1}{x}-\dfrac{e^{\frac{-x}{2}}-1}{x}\Bigg)^2=\dfrac{1}{2} \Bigg(\dfrac{1}{2}-\dfrac{-1}{2}\Bigg)^2=\dfrac{1}{2}$$

Answer (score 0):

Substitute $h=x^2$: it's $$\lim_{h \to 0} \frac{e^{\sqrt{h}}-\sqrt{h}-1}h$$
which is the derivative of $x \mapsto e^{\sqrt{x}}-\sqrt{x}$ evaluated at $x=0$.

Now use the chain rule: it's $$\lim_{x \to 0} \frac{e^{\sqrt{x}}-1}{2 \sqrt{x}} = \frac{1}{2}\lim_{h \to 0} \frac{e^h - 1}{h}$$

That latter limit is $\exp'(0)= 1$.

Comment: You are not trying to apply chain rule but rather trying to implicitly use the fact that if $g(x) =e^{\sqrt{x}} - \sqrt{x} $ then $g'$ is continuous on $[0,\infty)$. This requires that you already know that $g'(0)=1$. Instead you have proved that $\lim_{x\to 0}g'(x)=1$.

Answer (score -2):

$$e^x=1+x+\frac{1}{2}x^2+o(x^2)_{x\to0}\\
\lim_{x\to0}\frac{e^x-1-x}{x^2}=\lim_{x\to0}\frac{1+x+\frac{1}{2}x^2+o(x^2)-1-x}{x^2}=
\lim_{x\to0}\frac{\frac{1}{2}x^2+o(x^2)}{x^2}=\frac{1}{2}+0
$$
($f=o(x^2)\Leftrightarrow\lim_{x\to0}\frac{f(x)}{x^2}=0$)

Comment: i said only rules of algebra of limits and without expansion series