# How do i evaluate this limit :$\lim_{x \to 0} \frac{e^x-x-1}{x²}$ without using Taylor expansion

Tags: real-analysis, limits, exponential-function, limits-without-lhopital

I would like to evaluate this limit without using Taylor expansion:

$$\lim_{x \to 0} \frac{e^x-x-1}{x^2}$$ .

**Note:** by Taylor Expansion i have got  :$\frac{1}{2}$ .

Thank u for any help .!!!!

Comment: See if it helps: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/184053/how-to-find-lim-limits-x-to0-fracex-1-xx2-without-using-lhopitals-r?rq=1

Comment: What tools do you have at your disposal, exactly?

Comment: @user51189 Look even [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1908525/prove-this-limit-without-using-these-techniques-and-for-beginner-students-li?rq=1) and [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1179383/lim-x-to0-fracex-1-xx2-using-only-rules-of-algebra-of-limits?rq=1).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**METHODOLOGY $1$:**  Use L'Hospital's Rule Successively

Repeated use of L'Hospital's Rule reveals

$$\begin{align}
 \lim_{x\to 0}\frac{e^x-x-1}{x^2}&=\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{e^x-1}{2x}\\\\
&=\lim_{x\to 0}\frac12 e^x=\frac12 
\end{align}$$

---

**METHODOLOGY $2$:**  Integral representation of the numerator

Note that we can write the numerator as

$$\begin{align}
e^x-x-1&=\int_0^x \int_0^t e^s \,ds\,dt\\\\
&=\int_0^x \int_s^x e^s\,dt\,ds\\\\
&=\int_0^x (x-s)e^s\,ds
\end{align}$$

Now, we can use the Mean-Value-Theorem for integrals to reveal

$$\begin{align}
e^x-x-1&=e^{s^*(x)}\int_0^x(x-s)\,ds\\\\
&=\frac12 x^2e^{s^*(x)}
\end{align}$$

for some value of $s^*(x) \in (0,x)$.

Finally, exploiting the continuity of the exponential function yield the coveted limit

$$\begin{align}
\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{e^x-x-1}{x^2}&=\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{\frac12 x^2e^{s^*(x)}}{x^2}\\\\
&=\frac12
\end{align}$$

as expected!

Comment: sorry i forgot to say also without l'hopitale Role  because it's a question directed from student to me at high school

Comment: no  if u have other method just to post it in the side of ur answer

Comment: $s^*$ depends of $x$. Writing $s^*(x)$ can be better for beginners.

Comment: @Martín-BlasPérezPinilla Martin, yes, it does depend on $x$ since $s^*\in(0,x)$.  It is certainly more explicit to write $s^*(x)$ and I have edited to incorporate your implicit suggestion.  Thank you.  -Mark