# Finding $\lim\limits_{x\to0+} (\frac{e^x-1}{x})^{\frac1x}$ without Taylor's series.

Tags: limits

The solution on the textbook is $\sqrt e$. I assume I have to use the notable limit $$\lim_{x\to0+} (1+x)^{1/x}=e$$ after transforming the function into $((1+\frac x2)^{\frac 2x})^{\frac12}$ but I am stumped on the intermediate passages.

Comment: Just use taylor expansion of $e^x$ at $x=0$

Comment: Sorry, I should've specified in the title: no De L'Hopital and no Taylor either.

Comment: This is difficult without both

Comment: It is so simple with Taylor series.

Comment: No *Taylor* series?!  What are you allowed to use?  What is your definition of $e^x$?

Comment: What textbook is this?

Comment: Sorry everyone for the confusion, Hopital is allowed while Taylor isn't.
It's an Italian textbook so I don't expect it to help.
I'm studying IT, our program regarding limits begins and ends at notable limits, indeterminate forms and De L'Hopital.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given that
$$
\lim_{x\to0}\left(\frac{e^x-1}{x}\right)^{1/x}=\lim_{x\to0}\exp\left[{\frac{1}{x}\;\log\left(\frac{e^x-1}{x}\right)}\right]
$$
and that
$$
\lim_{x\to0}\frac{1}{x}\;\log\left[1+\left(\frac{e^x-1}{x}-1\right)\right]
=\lim_{x\to0}\frac{1}{x}\left(\frac{e^x-1}{x}-1\right)=\lim_{x\to0}\left(\frac{e^x-1-x}{x^2}\right)
$$
this other question could be relevant:

[How to find $\lim\limits_{x\to0}\frac{e^x-1-x}{x^2}$ without using l'Hopital's rule nor any series expansion?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/184053/how-to-find-lim-limits-x-to0-fracex-1-xx2-without-using-lhopitals-r)

Comment: I knew there must have been an easier approach than mine.

Answer (score 0):

If you take $\log$, and use the inequality
$$\frac{x-1}{x}\leq \log(x)\leq x-1$$
which is quite ideal around the value $x=1$ (which happens to be $\exp'(0)$), you can get the inequalities below:
$$\frac{e^x-x-1}{x^2}\cdot \frac{x}{e^x-1}=\frac{\frac{e^x-1}{x}-1}{\frac{e^x-1}{x}}\cdot\frac{1}{x}\leq\frac{\ln\left(\frac{e^x-1}{x}\right)}{x}\leq \frac{\frac{e^x-1}{x}-1}{x}=\frac{e^x-x-1}{x^2}$$

Both functions on the left and right tend to $1/2$, if you can show those instead.